# Sorting cells in a column is easy. But how to sort cells in a row?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Assume school language learning exercise, based on making right order of words in a scrambled sentence.

[image]

Then put numbers into the next row, specifying the order the words should be in.
Now select the 4×2 rectangular area, complete with the numbers.

[image]

Right click.
Arrange according numbers from low to high.

How? (make influence of arranging by lately added random numbers)

Comment: Select all, transpose to new range, sort range for number column, transpose again, copy back. Uff, not very intuitive

Comment: Pivot table might work.

Comment: nixda - dont get it + too many things to do.

Comment: raystafarian - dont know what is pivot. in my native language excel i have not that word.

Comment: i would like to make it with some macro if possible

Answer (score 4):

In the “Sort” dialog box, click on “Options” and select “Sort left to right”:

[image]

then,

[image]