# Excel 2010: sort all rows (each row separately) from smallest to largest value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to sort each row individually in a large database (Excel 2010)? 
The "sort" function doesn't provide that option for rows.

I have more than 1,000 rows to sort this way. The solution posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/626744/sorting-cells-in-a-column-is-easy-but-how-to-sort-cells-in-a-row) would require me to set up a sort for each row individually, which is unreasonable. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to ask: How do I sort the cells of each row in a worksheet? That if the first row starts 1, 3, 4, 2 it would be 1, 2, 3, 4 and if the second row were D, C, B, A it would be A, B, C, D?

Comment: Jason Aller,  yes, though all cells have numerical values.  I was aware of the method suggested by Scott but that requires each row to be sorted separately, which, for a spreadsheet of 1000 rows or more is not practical.

Comment: This is not an appropriate duplicate, since the linked question answers how to sort *one single* row, and this question asks how to sort *multiple* rows without manually selecting each row one at a time.

Answer (score -1):

To sort by a row, follow these steps:

- Select **one cell** in the row you want to sort.
- Press Ctrl + A, to
  select the entire region.
- Check the selected area, to make sure that
  all the data is included.
- Right-click a cell in the row that you want
  to sort In the popup menu, click Sort, then click Custom Sort.

[image]

- In the Sort dialog box, select the Day column in the Sort By box.
- From the Order drop down, select Custom List.
- At the top of the Sort
  dialog box, click Options.

[image]

- In the Options dialog box, under Orientation, select Sort Left to
  Right.

[image]

- Click OK, to close the Options dialog box.
- From the Sort By drop down, select the row that you want to sort. There are no headings
  available, so select the correct Row number.

[image]

- Select the Sort On, and the Order options, then click OK.

Comment: This does not answer the question.