# Not getting desired output in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
V      A      R      K
12     4      9      12
```

1. I need to view these values from Max to Min
2. Like 12,12,9,4
3. Then show relevant grades accordingly in separate cells

Comment: What grades?  Are the `V`, `A`, `R` and `K` "grades"?  If not, where do the grades come from?  Exactly what result do you want that you can't get from the "Sort" function?

Comment: Related: [Sorting cells in a column is easy.  But how to sort cells in a row?](http://superuser.com/q/626744/150988)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with data like:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub Zort()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:D2"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:D2")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

will produce this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a macro to do the sorting, as Gary's Student suggests, you can also do it like this from the sorting dialog:

[image]

Comment: I think you answer is very important since many people don't know that data can be sorted left-to-right.